# How to prevent Vlookup from returning empty rows when there is no match

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Vlookup to match to columns an different sheets and it is working

But when there is no match my formula returns an empty row

Is there a way to prevent the empty rows from being outputted

Thanks

`=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(Elements!C2:C, 'tab2'!$A$2:$P, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, 0)))`

Comment: What is meant by "empty row"?

Comment: A row with no data

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your formula in a query:

```
=query(y o u r   f o r m u l a, "where Col1 is not NULL")
```